# Tefillin Straps Cracking DIY Paint Suggestions

Tags: product-recommendation, tefilin

What are acceptable materials to color tefilin straps with? I don't have Amazon or similar where I am.

Comment: Actually it does NOT have an answer. You guys are out of control! How to close my account?

Comment: If you ask a question that is (for all intents and purposes) the same as another question on the site, it is a duplicate of that question, and should be marked as such. How is your question different from the other question?

Comment: Nobody is going to give you a link to a product in some mysterious place. The answers in the duplicate question tell you what to look for in a dye.

Comment: Suggest you use a black permanent marker.